# Equilibration of a solid body with two points particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, point-particles

How do I find $\theta$ as it $\theta (m,d,l) and AB=L$? And the cane which holds the two points particles(mass) is massless . In A the point mass is $3M$ and in B the mass is $M$ where there is no Friction in A and O . 
[image]

> I tried to apply  the summary of Torques equals 0 and get  $\theta= \frac{4L}{3d}$ but it's not correct because it should contain $M$ in it ... so I even tried Newton's first law and I got $M=0$  which is not logical .. what are the exact forces that are affecting this solid body?

Comment: Did you consider the normal force at A?

Comment: no ... what is it

Comment: You should have to include the normal force (Force acting perpendicular to the point of contact) at A and O."A Ladder Resting Against a Wall" is a similar problem you can refer. https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/12-2-examples-of-static-equilibrium/